# Windows INF files for multiple platforms and OS's

Tags: windows, inf

I am trying to create a Windows INF file to install a driver that can work with 32- or 64-bit Windows 7 or Windows 8.  I have 4 different .SYS files, all with the same name, one for each situation.  In my distribution I've created 4 directories, each of which contains a single driver file.

In the INF file, SourceDisksNames section I tried using the decorations .x86 and .amd64 and these will select correctly between installations on 32 and 64-bit Windows.

```
; 32-bit Windows
[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1=%DiskDescription%,,,"w7x86"

; 64-bit Windows
[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1=%DiskDescription%,,,"w7x64"
```

This works OK, except that I also need to select between Windows 7 and 8.  Reading the MSDN it says I can use supplemental decoration .6.1 (Windows 7) and .6.2 for Windows 8.  So I end up with a section names like

```
; 64-bit Windows 7 
[SourceDisksNames.amd64.6.1]

; 64-bit Windows 8
[SourceDisksNames.amd64.6.2]
```

However installation now cannot complete.  The dialog "Could not add the requested feature. The error is: The required Line was not found in the INF" is displayed.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.   A pointer to a working example would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using chkinf in the WDK to verify the structure of your INF file, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543461(v=vs.85).aspx? Clearly there are a required line missing. Have you added the correct diskid = disk-description under SourceDiskNames...?

Answer (score 0):

OS version decorators are not allowed in SourceDisksNames and SourceDisksFiles sections. See remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for details. 
You should use vesion decoration in manufacturer and model sections.